# Retrive all collection except one document id Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to retrieve all the collections except one document id. I have following query it will get all data by validating collection field. however i want to get all data except one document.

```
await Firestore.instance.collection('tbl').where('id',isEqualTo:textId).getDocuments().then(
        (data){
          dataRowCount= data.documents.length;
        }
      );
```

Answer (score 2):

Firestore doesn't offer any way to exclude documents from a query.  You must can only filter for known values that you're looking for, or ranges of values.  If you want to skip a document, you will have to check the query results in your code and omit the one you don't want

Comment: data.documents.forEach((col){
            if(col.documentID!=docId){
              //function
            }
          }); Like this?

Comment: That is exactly what is **not** possible.